# Using sections with OpenMP and MEX

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

I am trying to calculate 3x3 matrix inverse and multiply it by other 3x3 matrix. 
    The code for these calculations is working as a mex function.
    My problem start when I am trying to use OpenMP library.
    I have tried to make two parts of matrix inverse parallel, and I get many compile errors.
    When commenting the pragmas the code compilation is clean.
    Your help will be much appreciated.

```
/*==========================================================
 * inv_and_mul_3by3.c
 * inverse 3x3 matrix and multiply it by another 3x3 matrix
 * The calling syntax is: outMatrix = (mat_to_inv,mat_to_mul)
 *========================================================*/

#include "mex.h"
#include <omp.h>

/* The computational routine */
void inv_and_mul_3by3_omp(double *mat_to_mul, double *mat_to_inv, double *out)
{
    // Description : out = inv(mat_to_inv)*mat_to_mul
    double det;
    double det_2by2;
    double det_2by2B;
    double inversed[9];

    // Calculating 2x2 determinant that is being calculated for the 3x3 determinant
    // and also for matrix inversion
    det_2by2  = mat_to_inv[4]*mat_to_inv[8] - mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[5];
    det_2by2B = mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[5] - mat_to_inv[4]*mat_to_inv[2];

    /* Calculate the matrix deteminant */
    det = mat_to_inv[0]*(det_2by2) - mat_to_inv[3]*(mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[8]-mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[2])+mat_to_inv[6]*(det_2by2B);

        #pragma omp parallel sections
        {

        #pragma omp section {
            // Calcualte the inversed matrix
            inversed[0] = (det_2by2)/det;
            inversed[3] = (mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[5] - mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[8])/det;
            inversed[6] = (mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[7] - mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[4])/det;
            inversed[1] = (mat_to_inv[7]*mat_to_inv[2] - mat_to_inv[1]*mat_to_inv[8])/det;
        }

       #pragma omp section {
            inversed[4] = (mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[8] - mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[2])/det;
            inversed[7] = (mat_to_inv[6]*mat_to_inv[1] - mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[7])/det;
            inversed[2] = (det_2by2B)/det;
            inversed[5] = (mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[2] - mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[5])/det;
            inversed[8] = (mat_to_inv[0]*mat_to_inv[4] - mat_to_inv[3]*mat_to_inv[1])/det;
        }
   } /*-- End of sections block --*/


    // multiply the matrix by the the matrix that was inversed
    out[0] = mat_to_mul[0]*inversed[0] + mat_to_mul[3]*inversed[1] + mat_to_mul[6]*inversed[2];
    out[1] = mat_to_mul[1]*inversed[0] + mat_to_mul[4]*inversed[1] + mat_to_mul[7]*inversed[2];
    out[2] = mat_to_mul[2]*inversed[0] + mat_to_mul[5]*inversed[1] + mat_to_mul[8]*inversed[2];
    out[3] = mat_to_mul[0]*inversed[3] + mat_to_mul[3]*inversed[4] + mat_to_mul[6]*inversed[5];
    out[4] = mat_to_mul[1]*inversed[3] + mat_to_mul[4]*inversed[4] + mat_to_mul[7]*inversed[5];
    out[5] = mat_to_mul[2]*inversed[3] + mat_to_mul[5]*inversed[4] + mat_to_mul[8]*inversed[5];
    out[6] = mat_to_mul[0]*inversed[6] + mat_to_mul[3]*inversed[7] + mat_to_mul[6]*inversed[8];
    out[7] = mat_to_mul[1]*inversed[6] + mat_to_mul[4]*inversed[7] + mat_to_mul[7]*inversed[8];
    out[8] = mat_to_mul[2]*inversed[6] + mat_to_mul[5]*inversed[7] + mat_to_mul[8]*inversed[8];

} //end function

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *inMatToInv;             /* 3x3 input matrix that is inversed */
    double *inMatToMul;             /* 3x3 input matrix that multiply the inversed matrix*/
    double *outMatrix;              /* 3x3 output matrix */

    /* create pointers to the real data in the input matrix  */
    inMatToInv = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    inMatToMul = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    /* create the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3,3,mxREAL);

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
    outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* call the computational routine */
    inv_and_mul_3by3_omp(inMatToInv,inMatToMul,outMatrix);
}
```

This is the compile command I used in Matlab 
 
**mex inv_and_mul_3by3_omp.c COMPFLAGS="/openmp $COMPFLAGS"**

Here are the compile errors:
Error using mex
inv_and_mul_3by3_omp.c
(32) : error C3005: '{' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP
'section' directive 
(35) : error C3047: Structured block in an OpenMP 'sections'
region must be preceded by '#pragma omp section' 
(36) : error C3047: Structured block in an OpenMP 'sections'
region must be preceded by '#pragma omp section'
(37) : error C3047: Structured block in an OpenMP 'sections'
region must be preceded by '#pragma omp section'
(40) : error C3005: '{' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP
'section' directive 
(40) : error C3044: 'section' : only allowed directly nested
under an OpenMP 'sections' directive 
(47) : error C2059: syntax error : '}' 
(53) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(53) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(53) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(54) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts 
        (53) : see declaration of 'out' 
(54) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(54) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(54) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(55) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts 
        (53) : see declaration of 'out' 
(55) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(55) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(55) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(56) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts 
        (53) : see declaration of 'out' 
(56) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(56) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(56) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(57) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts 
(53) : see declaration of 'out' 
(57) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(57) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(57) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(58) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts
        (53) : see declaration of 'out'
(58) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(58) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
(58) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(59) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts 
        (53) : see declaration of 'out'
(59) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(59) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(59) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(60) : error C2369: 'out' : redefinition; different subscripts 
        (53) : see declaration of 'out'
(60) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier 
(60) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
(60) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
(62) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

Comment: Whoch erros you get?

Comment: Error using mex
(31) : error C3005: '{' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'section'
directive
(37) : error C3046: Missing structured block in an OpenMP '#pragma omp
sections' region
(38) : error C3005: '{' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'section'
directive
(38) : error C3044: 'section' : only allowed directly nested under an OpenMP
'sections' directive
(46) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
(51) : error C2065: 'mat_to_mul' : undeclared identifier
(51) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
(51) : error C2065: 'inversed' : undeclared identifier 
And more...

Comment: Mark, thanks for your comments. I have tried to do a basic thing of split the work load between two threads. I didn't try to do any nested parallelism. How should write what I meant ?

Comment: How are you compiling this? Edit your question to show your `mex` command and the results from the build / errors.

Comment: Always read your error messages closely.  `error C3005: '{' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'section'` - you can't have lines like `#pragma omp section {` any more than you can have lines like `#include <omp.h> {`; you can't start a code block on a preprocessor line.  Thus you have mismatched braces, and the compilation fails.  Move the open braces to new lines for the two sections, and the code should compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
#pragma omp section {
```

By this

```
#pragma omp section 
{
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd do is strip out the nested parallelism. It's not nearly as useful as many beginners think it ought to be, it's not necessarily available without setting up the compiler and/or environment variables, and it is rushing ahead when you ought to be taking baby steps.

Replace this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
```

with

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
```

and adjust the rest of the code accordingly.  To add to what I wrote above, it is usually a bad idea to try to specify the number of threads to use, leave that to the runtime system to figure out.

I don't pretend that this is a complete answer, but a step to simplify the code that may help illuminate where the error(s) are.

Comment: Mark, I have updated the code with your recommendations, but it didn't solve the compile errors I get

Comment: I didn't think it would.  You should edit your question to include the latest version of the code and the error messages that your compiler reports.